# Need to create value over time chart using Kibana 4

Tags: logstash, kibana-4

Am using logstash to store logfile containing the read time of a cable (specific to my application)

I would like to plot the graph of Cable Read Time (Y-Axis) over Elapsed Time (X-Axis) using Kibana.

Logstash config file looks as below

```html
input { 
  file { 
    path => "/opt/performanceMetrics.csv" 
    type => "core2"
    start_position => beginning
  } 
} 

filter {  
    csv {
        columns => ["Elapsed_Time_Hour", " Cable_read_time_avg_us", " Cable _read_time_max_us" ]
        separator => ","
    }
  mutate {
    convert => [ "Elapsed_Time_Hour ", "integer" ]
    convert => [ "Cable_read_time_avg_us", "integer" ]
    convert => [ "Cable_read_time_max_us", "integer" ]
  }
}

output {  
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        host => "localhost"
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        workers => 1
    } 
  stdout { codec => rubydebug } 
}
```

I could view the log files on Kibana, but I am unable to find a way to customize the Y-axis to have the value of Cable_Read_Time (instead of count).

Is there any thing incorrect with the logstash config file ?

Please suggest a way to customize the Y-axis on Kibana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Visualize tab, just under the query bar is your current index pattern.  Just under that are the metrics.  You probably have "Y-Axis...  Count".  Click the little arrow on the left of "Y-Axis" and select some other method from the Aggregation pulldown.

Comment: Thanks! I had to refresh the field under Settings -> Index Patterns after which the fields got listed under "Y-Axis... Average" and other methods from Aggregation pulldown